# Как перейти в настройки точки доступа android?

Tags: android, wifi, settings, hotspot

Пытаюсь по нажатию на кнопку производить переход в настройки точки доступа
minApi = 14(4.0) 
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел реализацию другого вида, она бросает прямо в настройки точки доступа вайфай, это не вызов через стандартные механизмы `Settings`, ссылку на эту активность нашел с помощью приложения `shortcutMaker`

```
void toHotspotStg(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.wifi.hotspot.TetherWifiSettings"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```